# Clicking one button then activate another button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click 1st button then activate 2nd button. After 2nd button is activated, 1st button will be disabled. I wrote the code below but it is not working. Where is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="button1" id="bt1">
<input type="button" name="button" value="button2" id="bt2" disabled="disabled">
</body>
<script>
$(function(){
        $("#bt1").click(function(){
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#bt2").removeAttr("disabled");
        });

        $("#bt2").click(function(){
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#bt1").removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    });
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: you din't added jQuery library file.That's the problem only

Comment: Here you go with fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vg76h03q/ .it's working perfectly

Comment: i forget . Thanks for remembering me :)

Comment: @Susant  you marked my answer first and then you marked another person answer? why? Any specific reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jQuery library file at the top of head tag like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(function(){
$("#bt1").click(function(){
$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#bt2").removeAttr("disabled");
});

$("#bt2").click(function(){
$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#bt1").removeAttr("disabled");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="button1" id="bt1">
<input type="button" name="button" value="button2" id="bt2" disabled="disabled">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

*You code is perfect,just add jQuery library and it will start working*

Check here:-

```js
$(function(){
  $("#bt1").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#bt2").removeAttr("disabled");
  });

  $("#bt2").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#bt1").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Edit Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="button1" id="bt1">
    <input type="button" name="button" value="button2" id="bt2" disabled="disabled">
  </body>
</html>
```